# Zapier line item manipulation with python

Tags: python, zapier

My zap runs a GET from Intercom which places all messages in a convo into a line-item field.

I want to change the entire line item field into a string without all the commas that zapier puts in when it joins all the values. So I can write the conversation as a text note elsewhere.

Someone at zapier suggested I should use join in code to do this but ofcourse they aren't allowed to give me the actual code.

Input:

```
input_data = {
    "values": "<p>Ok, I see your request. Give me just a minute to get it set up </p>,<p>ok</p>,<p>You should see the email shortly. When you get logged in, let me know if you have any other questions, I'm happy to help </p>,<p>cool</p>,<p>More Pipedrive testing</p>"
}
```

I tried the following code:

```
L = input_data['values']  
return {" ".join(str(x) for x in L)}
```

But got the following errors:

```
TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") 
TypeError: set(['< p > H i n e w b i e < / p >']) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Use a line break before indenting code in order to make it look right.

Comment: can you post some sample input and some of the errors you're getting?

Comment: Errors:  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 110, in decimal_serializer
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: set(['< p > H i    n e w b i e  < / p >']) is not JSON serializable

Comment: Sample input data:  
   <p>Ok, I see your request. Give me just a minute to get it set up </p>,<p>ok</p>,<p>You should see the email shortly. When you get logged in, let me know if you have any other questions, I'm happy to help </p>,<p>cool</p>,<p>More Pipedrive testing</p>

Comment: Input data is a conversation from a support tool. Feeds to zapier as a "line item" and Zapier puts those commas in between each value in the array. I'm trying to get rid of the commas (by changing the line-item "type" to a regular string within this code), and only return the last five values of the line item.

Answer (score 0):

Cool! So your issue is that you're returning a python `set` from your code step, which Zapier can't turn into json.

That's happening because you've got a string between curlies. See:

```
>>> {'asdf'}
set(['asdf'])
```

Your input is a big string with html in it. It seems like you could split on `</p>,<p>` and join on `' '`.

In either case, you need to return your output as a value:

```
>>> {'result': " ".join(str(x) for x in L.split('</p>,<p>'))}
{'result': "<p>Ok, I see your request. Give me just a minute to get it set up  ok You should see the email shortly. When you get logged in, let me know if you have any other questions, I'm happy to help  cool More Pipedrive testing</p>"}
```

You could also pull of the leading and trailing `<p>` tags if you'd like.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you SO much.

Comment: No problem! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and select it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))